# problem in file_put_contents Opensuse permissions

Tags: php, file, opensuse

I have this simple code:

```
<?php
$myFile ='test.txt';
$myContent ='Some text';
file_put_contents($myFile, utf8_encode($myContent));
?>
```

the location of the test.txt file is here:

```
/srv/www/htdocs/didebansnort
```

the page that I wrote this php code in browser:

```
http://localhost/didebansnort/testdl.php
```

the code is not working it will not write the string on it

RESULT:in properties it wasn't sufficient to set the permissions

Comment: Do you receive an error?

Comment: no error if I type for example `echo 'negin';` it will show me negin

Comment: Please put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', true);` in your script and run it again.

Comment: I put the both,again white page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the user PHP/Apache runs as has write permissions to that file.

In Linux, you can give read (r), write (w) and execute (x) rights either to yourself, your group(s) or everyone else. Make sure you either give write permissions to a group that has both you and the PHP user as members, or give write access to everyone (not to be used in production).

You're stating you use OpenSuse, you can find more details about permissions here:

- [7.3 File Access Permissions](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books//opensuse_guides/opensuse11.1_startup_guide/sec_new_users_accperm.html)
- [8.5 Modifying File Permissions](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books//opensuse_guides/opensuse11.1_startup_guide/sec_new_bash_perm.html)

Comment: You mean permissions? In properties of that text file I set permissions to READ and WRITE

Comment: @Negin To yourself, to your group, or the whole world?

Comment: what do you mean!!? bazmegakapa

Comment: @Negin Hm, are you using Linux?

Answer (score 0):

This this:

```
$myFile ='./test.txt';
```